# Counting number of rows connected to other table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL question.

I have 2 tables : Company & Products

Now i need to select rows in the Company table and count number of products for each company.

Here's an example:

```
Company:
---------------
| id   | Name |
---------------
| 1    | c1   |
| 2    | c2   |
| 3    | c3   |
| 4    | c4   |
---------------

Products:
--------------------
| id   | companyid |
--------------------
| 1    | 3         |
| 2    | 1         |
| 3    | 4         |
| 4    | 3         |
| 5    | 2         |
--------------------
```

And the result i need to get is :

```
----------------------------
| id   | Name | numproducts|
----------------------------
| 1    | c1   |  1         |
| 2    | c2   |  1         |
| 3    | c3   |  2         |
| 4    | c4   |  1         |
----------------------------
```

Sorry if the question is basic.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the 2 tables, then group by the field(s) you want from the companies table:

```
SELECT
      c.name
    , COUNT(p.id) AS no_of_products
FROM company c
      INNER JOIN products p
                  ON c.id = p.companyid
GROUP BY
      c.name
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use group by and count to get your answer

```
select 
  c.id, c.name, count(*) as numproducts 
from
  company c join products p on c.id = p.companyid 
group by 
  c.id, c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT * , 
     (SELECT COUNT( 1 ) 
           FROM products p2 WHERE p2.companyid = p1.id) AS no_of_records
FROM `company` p1
```